# Regex matching and printing string issue

Tags: regex, perl

In Perl, I am trying to match three groups. Some groups have two question marks around them, others have one. I need to be able to distinguish between the two.

**Sample Input:**

```
The box is ?Red? in colour.
The box is ??green?? in colour.
```

**Current Output:**

```
The box isRedin colour.

The box is green in colour.
```

**Desired Output:**

```
The box is Red in colour.

The box is green in colour.
```

Here is what is almost working perfectly:

```perl
my $pattern_q  = '(.*\s?)[^\?]\?(\w.*)\?[^\?](.*)';
my $pattern_qq = '(.*\s?)\?\?(\w.*)\?\?(.*)';

if ( $line =~ /$pattern_q/ ) {
    print "\n" . $1 . $2 . $3 . "\n";       
}

if ( $line =~ /$pattern_qq/ ) {
    print "\n" . $1 . $2 . $3 . "\n";
```

When I get a match against `$pattern_qq` - it handles everything correctly, except for the `\n` at the end, which I can live with.

When I get a match against `$pattern_q` - It removes the spaces between the three groups, which I want to retain.

Comment: Providing a sample input would be nice.

Comment: You may want to include the space in the `q` pattern like this: `([^?]+)\?(\w+)\?([^?]+)`

Comment: @revo - sample input and current/desired output added - thanks!

Comment: What is wrong with [**`$line =~ s/(\?{1,2})(\w+)\1(?!\?)/$2/;`**](https://regex101.com/r/xgQTcC/1)?

Comment: @HåkonHægland - That worked well! Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need to distinguish the two? Your desired output is the same in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

You said: *I need to be able to distinguish between the two*. But because your wanted output is the same in both cases and doesn't show any difference, in the following examples it is demonstrated by:

- the `??str??` going to be uppercase,
- the `?str?` lowercase.

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;

while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    say "orig: [$_]";
    s/ (\?(\?)?) (\w+?) (\1) / $2 ? uc($3) : lc($3) /gex;
    say "new : [$_]";
}

__DATA__
The box is ?Red? in colour.
The box is ??green?? in colour. 
The box is ?Red? but inside is an ??green?? one
Aren't nicer the ?blue?? Or the ??violet???
What?  ??blue?  ???violet??!
```

output:

```
orig: [The box is ?Red? in colour.]
new : [The box is red in colour.]
orig: [The box is ??green?? in colour. ]
new : [The box is GREEN in colour. ]
orig: [The box is ?Red? but inside is an ??green?? one]
new : [The box is red but inside is an GREEN one]
orig: [Aren't nicer the ?blue?? Or the ??violet???]
new : [Aren't nicer the blue? Or the VIOLET?]
orig: [What?  ??blue?  ???violet??!]
new : [What?  ?blue  ?VIOLET!]
```

you can also replace the `$2 ? uc($3) : lc($3)` with a subroutine call, like:

```
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    say "orig: [$_]";
    s/ (\?(\?)?) (\w+?) (\1) / make_result($3,$2) /gex;
    say "new : [$_]";
}

sub make_result {
    my($str, $two) = @_;
    return uc($str) if $two;
    return lc($str);
}
```

with the same output.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, your code is "almost working perfectly": it is very close to doing exactly what you want.

You can make it do exactly what you want by moving two parentheses in your first pattern to include the `[^\?]` pattern match in the capture groups.  This will capture the spaces on either side of `?Red?` in your sample input.

So

```
'(.*\s?)[^\?]\?(\w.*)\?[^\?](.*)'
```

becomes

```
'(.*\s?[^\?])\?(\w.*)\?([^\?].*)'
```

Answer (score -2):

Pure regex substitution example [here](https://regex101.com/r/gwaK4a/2/).

Perl script code (may test it [here](https://ideone.com/erGq9J)):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @strings = (
    'The box is ?Red? in colour.',
    'The box is ??green?? in colour.'
);

local $" = "\n\t";

print "Before:\n\t @strings\n";

s/\?+(\w+)\?+/$1/ for @strings;

print "After:\n\t @strings\n";
```

Comment: Don't use `map` in void context (`map` collects a list of results; why collect anything if you're just going to throw it away?). You can just write `s/\?+(\w+)\?+/$1/ for @strings;`.